# Insert PHP code in Heredoc to select the good option

Tags: php, heredoc

Hi currently working on a page to get a form corresponding to my database.
I want that the good option 'TYPE' gets selected corresponding to `$client['CLT_type']`

Here how my actual code looks (and what I tested)
But I get this error :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in 24

24 is my $select line

```
if($client = $requeteClt->fetch()) {

        $select = "<?php if($client['CLT_type']==2) echo 'selected'; ?>";

        $page->appendContent(<<<HTML
            <div id='res' height='800px'></div>
            <form id='form' name='form' method='POST' action='modifierClientScript.php' style='width:100%;'>
                <h2 style="text-align:center;">Modification du client {$client['CLT_libelle']}</h2>
                <p>
                    <label for='montant'>Nom :</label>
                    <input type='text' value='{$client['CLT_libelle']}' name='nom' id='nom'>
                    <span class="error" id="nomErr"></span>
                </p>
                <p>
                <label for='type'>Segmentation Client :</label>
                    <SELECT name='type' id='type'>
                        <optgroup label="Publics">
                            <OPTION value='1'>Etat
                            <OPTION value='2' {$select}>Collectivité
                            <OPTION value='3'>Entreprise publique
                        <optgroup label="Privés">
                            <OPTION value='4'>Entreprise de service
                            <OPTION value='5'>Entreprise industrielle
                            <OPTION value='6'>Autres
                    </SELECT>
                </p><br/>

                <p><br/>
                    <input type='button' name='submit' id='submit' value='Modifier le client'>
                </p>
            </form>
HTML
);
```

So is it possible to add PHP code in the Heredoc or do I have to manage my page by another way ?
Thx

Comment: Why putting php tag within php tag in the select line

Comment: Tried with and without, no change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your error fix.

```
$select = ($client['CLT_type']==2) ? 'selected' : null;
```

Never use `<?php` tags within `<?php` tags.

Comment: Is you HEREDOC syntax working though

Comment: I meant to say the appendContent(<<<HTML ...) part .. Because you have not closed your HTML Heredoc block

Comment: Ok then .. glad to help